# Delete Rows and Columns until specific range

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel workbook in which I search for a date in the heading using `.Find`.

For example if it is found in `RANGE("C3")` then it should remove **rows above** and **columns before** it.

Please help me write the VBA code to perform this operation.

```
Dim WSD As Worksheet
Set WSD = Worksheets("report")
Dim MyRange As Range
Set MyRange = WSD.Range("A:AZ")
Set R = MyRange.Find("Date", LookIn:=xlValues)
Debug.Print R.Address
```

Comment: So for all intents and purposes you are shifting Date to A1 ...?

Comment: yes. i want my header to start from 1 row and 1 column

Comment: my macro  which contains many modules is based on A1. rest all other are completed only for one sheet my progress is halted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
dim MyRange  as range

with Worksheets("report")
    Set MyRange = .Range("A:AZ").Find("Date", LookIn:=xlValues)
    if not MyRange is nothing then
        if MyRange.column > 1 then
            .cells(1, 1).resize(1, MyRange.column -1).entirecolumn.delete
        end if
        if MyRange.row> 1 then
            .cells(1, 1).resize(MyRange.row-1, 1 ).entirerow.delete
        end if
    end if
end with
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Jeeped. i really appreciate your support. it did solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

another way:

```
Dim MyRange  As Range
With Worksheets("report")
    Set MyRange = .Range("A:AZ").Find("Date", LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not MyRange Is Nothing Then MyRange.Resize(.UsedRange.Rows.Count + MyRange.Row, .UsedRange.Columns.Count + MyRange.Column).Cut Destination:=.Range("A1")
End With
```

Or

```
Dim MyRange  As Range
With Worksheets("report")
    Set MyRange = .Range("A:AZ").Find("Date", LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not MyRange Is Nothing Then
        .Rows(1).Insert
        .Columns(1).Insert
        With .Range("A1", MyRange)
            .Resize(, .Columns.Count - 1).EntireColumn.Delete
            .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).EntireRow.Delete
        End With
    End If
End With
```